# Using Django Rest Framework to show data from related models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to learn DRF on my on, for my self practice, wanted to create a member like API with three Models.

I'd like to join the contact data whenever I requested UserInfo; however, I googled, stackoverflowed many days without any directions. It'd be great if any gurus can guide me through this.
python: 3.7
django: 2.2.6
drf: 3.10.3

```py
# models.py
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    CID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    USER_ID = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    LOGIN_ID = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    USER_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    UPDATE_TIME = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        names = self.FIRST_NAME + " " + self.LAST_NAME
        return names

    class Meta:
        db_table = "myCustomers"

class ContactTypes(models.Model):
    CID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CONTACT_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.CONTACT_TYPE

class Contact(models.Model):
    CID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    USER_ID = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CONTACT_TYPE = models.ForeignKey(ContactTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CONTACT_INFO = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    UPDATE_TIME = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```py
# serializers.py
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'

class ContactTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactTypes
        fields = '__all__'

class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
# views.py
class myCustomersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserInfoSerializer

class contactsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

class contactTypesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ContactTypes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactTypeSerializer
```

Thanks for spending time with me

Comment: in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) explained very well how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  CONTACT_TYPE = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset = ContactTypes.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = [............,
                 CONTACT_TYPE,
]
```

This way you can relate your foreignkey to other models in your serializer class. Try to use small letters in your modeld field names, it is the convention.

Comment: I wanted the contacts to show when I pull UserInfo, this only shows contact related information :(
Still thanks for helping

Comment: similar way you can get that also

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who guided me through this 
I solved my questions by following:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = ContactSerializer(
        source='contact_set', many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = '__all__'
```